# Azure App Service API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

Looking in the Azure portal, I can see monitoring charts for API apps and Web apps that return information on metrics such as number of requests, cpu time, data i/o, etc.

Is there an API that I can query that will return information on Azure app services?

[image: Azure API App Monitoring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the list of web apps within a resource group, this can simply be achieved using the Azure Resource Manager API, which is the default API used by the new portal.

We now even have a cool tool to explore these APIs, check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/

The API Reference itself is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn790568.aspx

Comment: That API tool is awesome! Thank you. What I had to do in the end was use PowerShell to get a list of app services. I then used fiddler to monitor the underlying API request. I was able to get the underlying URI using PowerShell and Fiddler.

Comment: Ah! Fiddler always comes in handy for these. But you could have also easily figured out the same using the API explorer tool itself :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you search is named : "Azure Monitoring Services API".
You can get/set metrics.

You can access to the API by a Nuget package :

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring
```

Comment: [Related API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx) - I assume this is called by that library.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can.

Please refer to [Azure Insights REST API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931943.aspx).

Comment: Looking at that API, I don't see any endpoints that would give me a list of web applications, which is what I really want to accomplish. The only one I see that comes close is this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931952.aspx). Would this endpoint give me a list of the web applications in a resource group?